# Weblogic to Wildfly migration

Tags: ant, wildfly, weblogic

I have a *build.xml* file which calls the *buildWebService.xml* file for my java project, which contains many weblogic specific ant tags like ***wlaapc***, ***clientgen***, ***wsdl2service*** and ***autotype***. 
I am trying to migrate the project from weblogic server to wildfly server and tried to find the wildfly alternative for these tags, but couldn't find anything that works for me. 
I tried the ***wsconsume*** tag which is in the wildfly documentation that could be used for clientgen, but when I added it's jars and made the changes to the build file it gives an error that `<classpath> tag is not recognized`.

If someone has done something like this or has any idea regarding this, please point me in the correct direction on how I can achieve this and replace the weblogic tags with correct wildfly tags.

Update: The classpath error for wsconsume was resolved by removing it, and it was automatically able to capture the jars defined in the classpath.
But the problem still persists that it is not suitable for replacing the weblogic tasks that I mentioned above.

Comment: There are plenty of Maven tasks to help with this but your WLS ones will not likely work for Wildfly.  Post how you're using `wsconsume` in a new question and we can try to help.

Comment: @stdunbar I have updated the question as that classpath error is fixed, but still wsconsume cannot directly be used in place of the weblogic tags. Can they? How do you use wsconsume, if you have any example?

Comment: I would check out the [Maven plugin for wsconsume/wsprovide](https://github.com/jbossws/jaxws-tools-maven-plugin).  I know it's Maven and you said Ant but it's as close as I think you can get.